# WPF Datagrid Данные при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Есть датагрид с данными, в каждой строке есть кнопка, как при нажатии на кнопку получить данные в метод по событию кнопки из той строки, где она была?

```
<DataGrid Name="ManagerProductGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              IsReadOnly="True" SelectionChanged="ManagerProductGrid_SelectionChanged" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="№" Width="*" Binding="{Binding ProductId}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Модель"  Width="*" Binding="{Binding IdName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Производитель" Width="*" Binding="{Binding IdManufacturer}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Страна"  Width="*" Binding="{Binding IdCountry}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Тип" Width="*" Binding="{Binding IdType}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Цвет"  Width="*" Binding="{Binding IdColor}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Штрихкод" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Bartcode}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Работа со штрихкодом" Width="150" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Сгенерировать штрихкод" FontSize="12" Width="150" Height="20" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Изменение данных" Width="120" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Изменить" FontSize="12" Width="120" Height="20"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Удаление данных" Width="110" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Удалить" FontSize="12" Width="110" Height="20"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Привязки, `ICommand`, свойства, базовый набор. Нечто на подобии `<Button Command = "{Binding DataContext.SomeCommand, RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" CommandParameter = "{Binding}"/>`, примеров полно, даже здесь, на SO...

Comment: Все кнопки нужно привязать к одному событию, внутри обработчика этого события просто смотреть на забинденный SelectedItem, это при условии что при нажатии на кнопку в строке - эта строка становится выбранной - но так и надо делать